# Получить объект Company через Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Добрый день!
Подскажите, как выполнить такой запрос с помощью Hibernate

```
 select id, company_name, phone from company where company_name = 'Cristal' order by id DESC limit 1;
```

Comment: Hibernate SQL/HQL/Criteria?

Comment: @hmeli7 у вас есть мапинг таблиц? приложите в копросу ваш маппинг